# Jenkins Pipeline Error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using the pipeline plugin in Jenkins, but unable to run shell commands. I am receiving the following error:

```
[develop - pipeline] Running shell script
nohup: failed to run command ‘sh’: No such file or directory
```

The node is an Ubuntu instance.

```
node ('aws-ondemand') {

//println env.BUILD_NUMBER


try {
    stage 'Checkout and Build'


    git url: 'git@github.com:MyAndroidRepo.git',
    branch: 'develop'
    sh 'git submodule init'
    sh 'git submodule update'
    sh './gradlew clean build'

}catch (e) {
    //currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
    //notifyFailed()
    throw e
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Script is fine.  I was injecting env variables in the build step. I removed it and now its working.